# LaTeX pstricks pdf compilation without any specific configuration

Tags: latex, auctex, pdf

I changed the auctex style file  pstricks.el (from lines 779-784)

```
(TeX-add-style-hook
"pstricks"
(lambda ()
  (unless (or (member "pst-pdf" TeX-active-styles)
       (eq TeX-engine 'xetex))
-     (TeX-PDF-mode-off)
+   (setq TeX-PDF-from-DVI "Dvips"
+   (message "TeX-PDF-mode : on, TeX-PDF-from-DVI : Dvips"))
```

My LaTeX files compile gently to pdf using C-c C-a (TeX-command-run-all) whether the tex file use pstricks package or not.

As I am not a real elisp wizard, I wonder if there is a side effect that I missed and that could cause me some future trouble ?

Comment: What was wrong with it originally? Why did you change it?

Comment: the style file pstricks.el set the compilation mode  dvi, not pdf ; (TeX-PDF-mode-off). dvi file have to be manually convert to ps and pdf

Comment: with my modified code, the pdf is directly viewed with pdf-tools in an Emacs buffer

Comment: OK - thanks for the clarification.

Comment: There is a very recent discussion about this in the AUCTeX mailing list. You might be interested in the thread: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/auctex/2020-07/msg00004.html

Comment: I think this feature can be a great feature as the issue of setting up to compile pstricks code is a real issue, mainly for users who are a bit clumsy with using system commands.

Comment: It seems it just landed upstream: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/auctex/2020-08/msg00004.html